# Javascript reading multidimensional form

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, forms, http-post

This has driven me "doo-lally" this afternoon!

A vendor (Zaxaa) uses a multi-dimentional form thus:

```
<form method="post" name="zaxaa" action="xxxx">
<input type="text" name="products[0][prod_name]" value="ABC">
<input type="text" name="products[0][prod_type]" id="pt" value="FRONTEND">
</form>
```

** This is my understanfing of how a multdimentional array is set up, and it seems to pass the variables to the server OK.

However, dependant on what other inputs are set to on the test form, the [prod_type] (and others) may need to change to "OTO" This is obviously going to be a javascript function, (but not the variant that starts with "$" on code lines ... whatever that type is!)

I have tried

- `document.zaxaa.products[0].prod_type.value`
- `document.getElementById('products[0][prod_type]').value`
- `document.getElementsByName('products[0][prod_type]').value`

but in everycase, I get "products is not defined". (I have simplified the form as there are ten product[0] fields)

---

I've solved it... mainly a glaring error on my part. The getElementById worked fine ... except in my test script I'd used getElementById[xxx] and not getElementById(xxx)!! ie "[" rather than "(" Does help if you get the syntax right!

But I will take notice of those other methods, such as enclosing both array arguments in ["xxx"].

Comment: *variant that starts with "$"* sorry but, I laughed.

Comment: Yer, I'm still ignorant to whatever that type is. Care to enlighten? Only time I use "$" is on server-side PERL scripts, not in my HTML code. Am I missing something? Is it a new way to write Javascript? Shorthand??

Comment: Sorry but I didn't mean you're ignorant. I just thought it was a little funny. The symbol is commonly used by a JavaScript framework called [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/). Here's a [nice introduction](http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/intro/) of *what is it*. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById` didn't work because the only one of those elements that has an `id` is the second input, with `id="pt"`.

On [any modern browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), you can use `querySelector` to get a list of the inputs using a CSS selector:

```
var nameInput = document.querySelector('input[name="products[0][prod_name]"]');
var typeInput = document.querySelector('input[name="products[0][prod_type]"]');
```

Then use their `value` property. So for instance, to set the name to `"OTO"`:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="products[0][prod_name]"]').value = "OTO";
```

Use `querySelectorAll` if you need a list of relevant `input`s, e.g.:

```
var nameInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="products[0][prod_name]"]');
```

Then loop through them as needed (the list as a `length`, and you access elements via `[n]` where `n` is `0` to `length - 1`).

---

Re

> * This is my understanfing of how a multdimentional array is set up...

All that HTML does is define `input` elements with a `name` property. That name property is sent to the server as-is, repeated as necessary if you have more than one field with that name. Anything turning them into an array for you is server-side, unrelated to JavaScript on the client. (The `[0]` is unusual, I'm used to seeing simply `[]`, e.g `name="products[][prod_name]"`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can access it in this syntax:

```
document.zaxaa['products[0][prod_name]'].value
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> document.zaxaa.products[0].prod_type.value
> ```

The name is a single string, not making a nested structure to access the input. It would need to be

```
document.zaxaa["products[0][prod_type]"].value
// or better:
document.forms.zaxaa.elements["products[0][prod_type]"].value
```

The complicated name does only serve to parse the data into a (multidimensional) array on the server side, but all data will be sent "flattened".

> ```
> document.getElementById('products[0][prod_type]').value
> ```

The `id` of your input is `pt`, so this should work as well:

```
document.getElementById("pt").value
```

> ```
> document.getElementsByName('products[0][prod_type]').value
> ```

[`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) does return a collection of multiple elements - which does not have a `.value` property itself. Instead, access the first element in the collection (or iterate it completely):

```
document.getElementsByName('products[0][prod_type]')[0].value
```